Loading {ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css in ASP .NET Core 8 Solution
I'm developing a solution with VS22 structured with the projects Core, Application, Infrastructure, Web (Blazor Web App), and Main (Console Application). The Main project serves as the Composition Root, so I added the following line to the .csproj file of the Web project:
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
To resolve the issue of static files not loading from the wwwroot folder of the Web project, I included the following lines in the .csproj file of the Web project:
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

This solved the issues with the files in wwwroot, such as favicon.png, but it did not resolve the problem with the scopedcss "Web.styles.css," which is generated inside the obj/debug/net8.0/scopedcss subfolder but is not correctly loaded by the application. When accessing localhost:5000, I encounter the following errors in the console:
FWA.Web.styles.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
FWA.Web.styles.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

How can I solve?
I've tried several tests and read various articles on the web, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue in any way.

In your program.cs in the web project, Is there the code app.UseStaticFiles();? If not, you should add it, and the reference to the UseStaticFiles() middleware should precede other middleware that might depend on static files, ensuring that the static files middleware can correctly serve static resources when handling requests. Then remove the line <OutputType>Library</OutputType>, and check if the application can work.
